# Are there any rails libraries to use with twitter oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a plugin or a helper to help me with building a Twitter Rails app, stuff like signing in with Twitter, listing the users followers, etc. What is the best one out there?

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://twitter.rubyforge.org/ I find it to be the one with the best documentation.
If you want to do more than simple API calls and go for user authentication as well look into 
using devise with twitter https://github.com/MSch/devise-twitter

Answer (score 0):

Railscasts has covered this in several episodes:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=twitter

Answer (score 0):

You can use
omniauth which can also cover services like github and facebook (if you feel like expanding)
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth
with the twitter strategy
omniauth-twitter (can't post link because of not enough rep, google it yo)

there are some railscasts that look over how you can integrate the two and this nettuts article which will give you an overall description of omniauth & providers
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/